# Is there a way to push the history inside a store or a global array without copy pasting code on every page?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Is there a way to push the history inside a store or a global array without copy pasting code on every page?

I need to use React Router and useHistory to push the path and location every time I visit 50 of 100 pages in an application, only 50 of them should have this behavior. Is there a way to achieve this without copy pasting the same code inside 50 pages?

The only way I know of is to just create an util function inside a file and then copy paste the function call on all 50 pages, but it's still too much copy pasting.

Comment: Why not make a React HOC component to handle this? I would call it something like `withPageRedirect`. then you just need to export your pages wrapped with it. `export default withPageRedirect(MyPage)`. If you can provide some code to give an example of what you are trying to accomplish you'll get a more specific solution :)

Comment: What *specific* version of `react-router` are you trying to work with, and *what* features of it are you trying to generally use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are already using Redux in your app and wish to connect `react-router` to the Redux store then I'd suggest integrating [redux-first-history](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history). It is compatible with all of `react-router@6` ***other than*** the new Data routers that were introduced in RRDv6.4.

The redux history context configuration setting you want to be aware of is the `savePreviousLocations` property. See the [options](https://github.com/salvoravida/redux-first-history#options) for more details.

> ```
> export const createReduxHistoryContext = ({
>   history, 
>   routerReducerKey = 'router', 
>   reduxTravelling = false, 
>   selectRouterState = null,
>   savePreviousLocations = 0, <---
>   batch = null,
>   reachGlobalHistory = null
> })
> ```

> savePreviousLocations: if > 0 add the key "previousLocation" to
> state.router, with the last N locations. [{location,action}, ...]

### Basic Setup

Create the store and history object

```
import { configureStore, combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { createReduxHistoryContext } from 'redux-first-history';
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history'; // history@5

const {
  createReduxHistory,
  routerMiddleware,
  routerReducer
} = createReduxHistoryContext({ 
  history: createBrowserHistory(),
  savePreviousLocations: 50, // last 50 history entries
  // other options if needed 
});

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  ... all other reducers ...
  router: routerReducer,
});

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleWare) =>
    getDefaultMiddleWare(defaultMiddlewareConfig)
      .concat(... all other middlewares ..., routerMiddleware),
});

export const history = createReduxHistory(store);
```

Pass `store` to Redux `Provider`, pass `history` to RRD `HistoryRouter`.

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { unstable_HistoryRouter as HistoryRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { store, history } from "./store";

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <HistoryRouter history={history}>
      //.....
    </HistoryRouter>
  </Provider>
);
```

From here you can simply select the `state.router.previousLocations` array from the store in the app.

Note, if still using `react-router-dom@5` then import the low-level `Router` component from `react-router-dom` and ***ensure*** you have `history@4` installed (*`history@5` is incompatible with RRDv5*).